# Doxygen maximum characters in page

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I meet a the following error: **label raul_1 is a subpage of itself! Please remove this cyclic dependency.**
The following content is used for creating the page and subpage. After some debugging session I observed that if I have in the above page more then 264000 characters then I got this error. If the number of character is lower, there is no issue. Are you aware about any limitation on characters number ? Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

```
|SWC               | Namespace         | File
|------------------| ------------------|------------------
|func1|std|\subpage raul_1|


\page raul_1 r1
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is the name of the file used and is all the code you provided in that file and is it all the code? What settings are you using different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)?

Comment: There are some limits in the lexers used by doxygen (and they are around 262144 characters). Looks a bit like your input file contains a string or something else that is very long or not closed. For this we need the complete file used, so best is to file an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (as here it is easier to add files as attachments).